# DropdownSearch asyncItems not shown

Tags: flutter

I am using this package
[dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)

```
DropdownSearch<MakeModel>(
          asyncItems: (String? filter) => getMake(filter),
          itemAsString: (MakeModel makeModel)=>makeModel.brand,
          onChanged: (value){
            print(value);
          },
        )
```

My question is **why does asyncItems not shown?** it keeps telling me no data found , I tried to print the items and was sure that it was triggered

Comment: what are you passing to `itemAsString` and `asyncItems`? attach them too

Comment: I put print in the function and it works whenever I click the dropdown it is called and the list is received perfectly, My problem is it does not update at all